# How to return to the previous screen with auto_route package?

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

In my project, I use autogeneration of routes using auto_route. I just started working with this package, so I don't understand what method can be used to return to the previous screen. I have this code for my TextButton and I need to implement onPressed method.

```
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //AutoRoute.of(context).popRoute();
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Close',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says this on pub.dev:

```
context.router.pop();
```

It's a context extension, so this should also work:

```
AutoRouter.of(context).pop();
```

Also this helper method should work:

```
context.back();
```